# How to deploy a project made in PHP with .htaccess in Google APP Engine?

Tags: php, css, google-app-engine

I hope you can help me, I have the following problem: I am uploading my PHP project to Google App Engine, when I deploy everything is fine, but when I show it in the browser, I do not send, inspect the console and mark me css file errors.

One of the mistakes I usually get is this: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text / javascript

and

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

My structure of my project is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJGd8.png)

and the structure the app.yaml file is as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgfrL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by following some tutorials.

You can find below documentation on how to deploy PHP app on Google App Engine:

1.[Deploying a PHP 5 App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/uploadinganapp)

2.[Run Laravel on Google App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard)